# try catch not working Java

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, try-catch

I am trying to use try-catch statement in JAVA in a while loop, just to catch the exception when string input is given to nextInt, I don't know why it keeps on raising the exception after the first incorrect input.

Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class People{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
                Scanner inS=new Scanner(System.in);
                int i=0;
                System.out.println("Enter number of people");
                int n=in.nextInt();
                int[] age=new int[n];
                String[] name=new String[n];
                double[] aIncome=new double[n];
                while (i<n){
                        try{

                                System.out.println(i+"Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is \"Rahul Gupta\" then enter \"Gupta Rahul\") : ");
                                name[i]=inS.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Now putting name");
                                System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
                                age[i]=in.nextInt();
                                System.out.println("Now putting age");
                                System.out.println("Enter your annual income: ");
                                aIncome[i]=in.nextDouble();
                                System.out.println("Now putting income");
                                i++;
                        }
                        catch(Exception InputMismatchException){
                                System.out.println("Error !! Wrong input, Please try again.");

                        }
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(age));
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aIncome));
        }
}
```

When correct input is given.

```
Script started on Sat 03 Feb 2018 07:55:42 PM NST
amehla@slbnen3000pc50:~/Desktop/test$ jva KKKava People.K
Enter number of people
3
0Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is "Rahul Gupta" then enter "Gupta Rahul") : 
harit Gupta
Now putting name
Enter your age: 
26
Now putting age
Enter your annual income: 
59495
Now putting income
1Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is "Rahul Gupta" then enter "Gupta Rahul") : 
Rahul Gupta
Now putting name
Enter your age: 
59
Now putting age
Enter your annual income: 
35695
Now putting income
2Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is "Rahul Gupta" then enter "Gupta Rahul") : 
Shikha kom
Now putting name
Enter your age: 
56
Now putting age
Enter your annual income: 
59565
Now putting income
[26, 59, 56]
[harit Gupta, Rahul Gupta, Shikha kom]
[59495.0, 35695.0, 59565.0]
```

But when incorrect input is given, this goes on infinite times.

```
amehla@slbnen3000pc50:~/Desktop/test$ java People
Enter number of people
3
0Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is "Rahul Gupta" then enter "Gupta Rahul") : 
Rahul Gupta
Now putting name
Enter your age: 
59
Now putting age
Enter your annual income: 
fasdf
Error !! Wrong input, Please try again.
0Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is "Rahul Gupta" then enter "Gupta Rahul") : 
Rahul Gupta
Now putting name
Enter your age: 
Error !! Wrong input, Please try again.
0Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is "Rahul Gupta" then enter "Gupta Rahul") : 
Rahu lasdf
Now putting name
Enter your age: 
Error !! Wrong input, Please try again.
0Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is "Rahul Gupta" then enter "Gupta Rahul") : 
asdf adsf
Now putting name
Enter your age: 
Error !! Wrong input, Please try again.
0Enter your last and first name (for e.g. if full name is "Rahul Gupta" then enter "Gupta Rahul") : 
^Camehla@slbnen3000pc50:~/Desktop/test$ exit
exit

Script done on Sat 03 Feb 2018 07:57:22 PM NST
```

Would be a great help, Even if someone replies.

Thank You.

Comment: why on Earth are you calling a *variable* "InputMismatchException" (upper case)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Adding a `in.nextLine();` in your catch might just fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something weird going on with the newlines when you mix and match `nextLine()` and `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()` or any of those. If you replace the calls to `nextInt()` and `nextDouble()` in your code with `Integer.valueOf(inS.nextLine())` and `Double.valueOf(inS.nextLine())`, that should fix your issue.

As a general rule, if you're reading any user input at the command line, you should read the entire line and parse the whole line. Don't try to grab individual tokens, it gets really messy.

Answer (score 0):

When you are typing your input value, you accept it by pressing `Enter` key. It generates new line character after the inputted value. When in some of next lines of codes you call `nextLine()` method, it reads the remaining new line character instead of input you type. To clear the new line character after calling `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()`, put `nextLine()` right after these methods.

Another possibility is to call methods like `Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine())` or `Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine())`, as they automatically get rid of remaining new line character.

You should also think of putting `in.nextLine()` method in `catch` block to get rid of remaining new line character when input throwing an exception has been provided:

Another issue that is present in your code is this part:

```
catch(Exception InputMismatchException) {...}
```

With that code you catch **ANY** type of `Exception` - not only `InputMismatchException` but any other type inheriting from `Exception` class and `Exception` itself - first in the brackets goes class of `Exception` you want to catch and then the name you want to call it with within `catch` block - change it to:

```
catch(InputMismatchException ex ) {...}
```

That way you will catch only `InputMismatchException.`

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code, and I found three changes that will fix your problem.

First of all - you don't need two Scanners. Just use one. Get rid of `in2` entirely.

Next - getting rid of `in2` kind of messes up the line `name[i]=inS.nextLine();`
You can fix it by changing it to this: `name[i]=in.next();`
I'm not sure exactly why this fixes the problem, but here is my best guess (other users, please speak up if you know more about this!):

When you used `nextLine()`, the scanner was looking for everything before the next `\n` character. In the previous call to the scanner in the `int n=in.nextInt();` line, the scanner only read in the number itself, and not the corresponding `\n` newline character which the user enters when they enter the number. Therefore, calling `in.nextLine()` will cause the Scanner to read in the same value that was meant to be the name again. We don't want that - we want to read in just the next *token* that the user enters, which `next()` does very nicely.

Lastly - I also changed the line `catch(Exception InputMismatchException){...` to the more conventional way of writing a catch statement: `catch(InputMismatchException e){...`

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite get the problem, but I guess what you want is to exit the loop after the first exception is thrown? Then instead of having

```
while (...) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

you can write

```
try {
    while (...) {
        ...
    }
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

or just add a `break` statement in your catch block to exit the surrounding `while` loop.